# Display message in TextArea when tab presed in TextField in java

Tags: java

The following code was supposed to make the program detect when tab is pressed in a certain JTextField (called timeStep) and display a message in a TextArea (called textAreaInsructions), but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please tell me why?

```
timeStep.setFocusTraversalKeys(
                KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, Collections.EMPTY_SET);

        timeStep.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
                if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB){
                    instruction = "Enter a real number time step";
                    textAreaInstructions.setText(instruction);
                    /* If you want to change the focus to the next component */
                    //nextJComponent.grabFocus();
            }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The TAB key is already eaten by most swing components, since it is tied to the field focus control. There's more than one way to handle it, you can try alternatives:

Instead of explicity listening for the TAB key, you can use a FocusListener to simply detect when the focus leaves the text field.

*or*

Register a keyboard action: JComponent.registerKeyboardAction(action, keystroke, WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW); for the TAB key.

Comment: I had thought of trying your first suggestion, but I wanted to know how to make pressing tab the only way to change the displayed instructions.

Comment: Java has this fantastic thing called Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/. Use it.

Comment: JComponent.registerKeyboardAction is now obsolete, but it seems to have put me on the right track. I now need to work out how to use getInputMap() and getActionMap(). The arguments of getInputMap() are (KeyStroke, Object) while those of getActionMap() are (Object, Action). Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Two things: Obsolete in java means *we decided to add yet another API and we prefer you to use that* (because we screwed up our API design the first three tries...). As of now, no methods have *ever* been removed from a public API (Java has been nicknamed "The new Cobol" for that). When there is mention of an alternate approach - the javadocs are excessively linked - follow the links to the alternate methods. If a signature doesn't make immediate sense, read the details and navigate to the description of the types (e.g. InputMap), there is also a *class* description that will describe the use.

Comment: ... and you will find InputMap maps KeyStrokes to ActionKeys. I would use registerKeyBoardAction btw. Its much less work.

Comment: lol. Thanks. I've been trying to follow the intructions here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html but haven't been able to make it work as yet. I might try looking at the API. Ok- I might go for registerKeyBoardAction.

Comment: You're on a good track. It may seem tedious to figure out things like that in a autodicative way, but you will learn a lot more (There's a simple 3-liner in the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying to be patient. I think if I can't do something patiently, then either I shouldn't be doing it or I need a break. I've actually been looking at the 3 liner you mentioned: no joy as yet, but I might take a look at the sample program they provide. +1's (answer and comments) for your help so far.